# org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class

Tags: java, hibernate-mapping

The configuration for User class :

```
<class name="User" table="users" lazy="false">
    <id name="id" column="id">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>        
    <property name="type" column="type"/>         
    <many-to-one name="parent" column="parent"/>
    <property name="loginName" column="login_name" unique="true" not-null="true" index="idx_users_login_name" length="50"/>
    <property name="name" column="name" length="50"/>
    <property name="password" column="password"/>
    <property name="email" column="email" length="50"/>
    <property name="locale" column="locale" length="20"/>
    <property name="locked" column="locked"/>
    <many-to-one name="metadata" column="metadata_id"/>
    <set name="userSpaceRoles" cascade="all" inverse="true" lazy="false">
        <key column="user_id"/>
        <one-to-many class="UserSpaceRole"/>
    </set>      
</class>
```

and for the class MeetingItem is:

```
<class name="MeetingItem" table="meeting_item">
    <id name="id" column="meeting_item_id" type="long">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="summary" column="summary" type="string"/>
    <property name="detail" column="detail" type="string"/>
    <many-to-one name="space" column="space_id"/>
    <property name="date" column="date" type="date"/>
    <list name="users" cascade="all" lazy="false">
        <key column="meeting_item_id"/>
        <index column="idx"/>
        <one-to-many class="User"/>
    </list>
</class>
```

The problem is I am getting the exception:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: info.domain.User
at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindCollectionSecondPass(HbmBinder.java:2380)
at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindListSecondPass(HbmBinder.java:2231)
at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder$ListSecondPass.secondPass(HbmBinder.java:2729)
at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:43)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1130)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.generateSchemaUpdateScript(Configuration.java:936)
at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:140)
```

The mapping of the list is creating the problem. What I am doing wrong?

---

Edit:

This two configuration resides in different file, if these two are placed in same xml then the problem is not occurring.

Answer (score 5):

please add a reference to the mapping file (which maps `info.domain.User`) into hibernate.cfg.xml.

Comment: thanks. But I don't have hibernate.cfg.xml, as everything is controlled by Spring. Also the table corresponding to info.domain.User is created before the attempt for creating info.domain.MeetingItem.

Comment: you must be linking the mapping files (.hbm.xml) to spring.. you need to add the mapping file for `info.domain.User` class there.

Answer (score 0):

Please add class level annotations to register the class as a Spring bean, i.e @Entity in this case since you are not using xml configuration.